# Error calling COM DLL in asp.net webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, com, asmx

I am attempting to call a COM component (that lives in component services) via a local web service but it fails with the following error:

Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

I have created a C# windows app that does exactly the same thing and calls the COM component fine every time. I assumed this was a security issue so I have added Everyone to the access permissions for component services but this doesn't help. Any suggestions? Could it be a 64 bit related issue?

Versions:
VS2008, .NET 3.5, Windows 7, 64 bit

Comment: Is this component registered system-wide, or per-user? ASP.NET will be running as a different user.

Answer (score 1):

On a 64-bit version of Microsoft Windows, it is possible to run 32-bit applications using the WOW64 emulator. However, processes can only be 32-bit or 64-bit. You cannot have a process that runs both.

Try creating a new interop dll too